# macOS Sierra 10.12.4でMySQL-Pythonがインストールできない (pip)

Tags: python, mysql, macos, pip

MAMPでPythonのWebアプリケーション開発を行っているのですが, PythonのMySQL-Pythonがエラーでインストールできません. 調べてみたところMySQL-Pythonのインストールに関してエラーが発生するケースが多いようですが, 色々調べて試してみたもののうまくいきません.
以下, ターミナルのログです.

### エラー

```
$ sudo pip install mysql-python
The directory '/Users/Owner/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/Owner/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting mysql-python
  Downloading MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip (108kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 112kB 1.2MB/s 
Installing collected packages: mysql-python
  Running setup.py install for mysql-python ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-2QuhFE/mysql-python/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-wx4saf-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7
    cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 -I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.14/include/mysql -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/_mysql.o -fno-omit-frame-pointer
    In file included from _mysql.c:44:
    /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.14/include/mysql/my_config.h:174:9: warning: 'SIZEOF_LONG' macro redefined [-Wmacro-redefined]
    #define SIZEOF_LONG      8
            ^
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pymacconfig.h:54:17: note: previous definition is here
    #        define SIZEOF_LONG             4
                    ^
    In file included from _mysql.c:44:
    /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.14/include/mysql/my_config.h:179:9: warning: 'SIZEOF_TIME_T' macro redefined [-Wmacro-redefined]
    #define SIZEOF_TIME_T    8
            ^
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pymacconfig.h:57:17: note: previous definition is here
    #        define SIZEOF_TIME_T           4
                    ^
    _mysql.c:1589:10: warning: comparison of unsigned expression = sizeof(row_converters)) {
                ~~~ ^ ~
    3 warnings generated.
    _mysql.c:287:14: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                    cmd_argc = PySequence_Size(cmd_args);
                             ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:317:12: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                    groupc = PySequence_Size(groups);
                           ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:470:14: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                            int j, n2=PySequence_Size(fun);
                                   ~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:1127:9: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                    len = mysql_real_escape_string(&(self->connection), out, in, size);
                        ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:1129:9: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                    len = mysql_escape_string(out, in, size);
                        ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:1168:9: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
            size = PyString_GET_SIZE(s);
                 ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/stringobject.h:92:32: note: expanded from macro 'PyString_GET_SIZE'
    #define PyString_GET_SIZE(op)  Py_SIZE(op)
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/object.h:116:56: note: expanded from macro 'Py_SIZE'
    #define Py_SIZE(ob)             (((PyVarObject*)(ob))->ob_size)
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:1178:9: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                    len = mysql_real_escape_string(&(self->connection), out+1, in, size);
                        ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:1180:9: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                    len = mysql_escape_string(out+1, in, size);
                        ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:1274:11: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
            if ((n = PyObject_Length(o)) == -1) goto error;
                   ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/abstract.h:434:25: note: expanded from macro 'PyObject_Length'
    #define PyObject_Length PyObject_Size
                            ^
    _mysql.c:1466:10: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                            len = strlen(buf);
                                ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:1468:10: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                            len = strlen(buf);
                                ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:1504:11: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                                    len = strlen(buf);
                                        ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:1506:11: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                                    len = strlen(buf);
                                        ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:1589:10: warning: comparison of unsigned expression = sizeof(row_converters)) {
                ~~~ ^ ~
    14 warnings generated.
    cc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -Wl,-F. build/temp.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/_mysql.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.14/lib -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/_mysql.so
    ld: library not found for -lssl
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-2QuhFE/mysql-python/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-wx4saf-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-2QuhFE/mysql-python/
```

### Pythonのバージョン

2.7.10です.

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.10
```

ご教授お願いいたします.

Comment: エラーメッセージに `ld: library not found for -lssl` とありますので、libssl(OpenSSL)がインストールされていないのだと思われます。

Comment: `pip freeze`でpyOpenSSLが入っていることは確認したのですが, どうやらバージョンが古すぎたようです. `brew unlink openssl && brew link openssl --force`したところ新しいバージョンにリンクされたようで, その後は`$ sudo pip install MySQL-Python`でインストールに成功しました. ご教授ありがとうございました. [error installing psycopg2, library not found for -lssl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26288042/error-installing-psycopg2-library-not-found-for-lssl)

Answer (score 1):

`pip freeze` で pyOpenSSL が入っていることは確認したのですが, どうやらバージョンが古すぎたようです.

`brew unlink openssl && brew link openssl --force` を実行したところ新しいバージョンにリンクされたようで, その後は `$ sudo pip install MySQL-Python` でインストールに成功しました.

[error installing psycopg2, library not found for -lssl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26288042/error-installing-psycopg2-library-not-found-for-lssl)

---

*この投稿は [@david_0717 さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/33938/macos-sierra-10-12-4%e3%81%a7mysql-python%e3%81%8c%e3%82%a4%e3%83%b3%e3%82%b9%e3%83%88%e3%83%bc%e3%83%ab%e3%81%a7%e3%81%8d%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84-pip#comment33475_33938) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*